# Avoid page break on Html

Tags: html, printing, page-break

I tried to avoid page-break when printing but no success,

```
tr { page-break-inside:avoid;}
```

as you see in image the total breaks in middle , how to avoid that ?? thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcX8H.png

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media query

```
@media print
```

And inside of it, use your style